# Hot Spot Analysis using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clustering, hot-spot

I have a point shape containing locations of cars and a line shape containing roads.
Now I want to identify hotspots/clusters.

I want to find hot spots where for example the speed of the cars is very high/ very low. How can I do this in ArcGIS for Desktop? Should I use the [Hot Spot Analysis](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/hot-spot-analysis.htm) tool here?

Comment: I would review the help for [Optimized Hot Spot Analysis (Spatial Statistics)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005p00000058000000) and try that.  If you get stuck then you will be in a position to describe what you tried and where you are stuck via an edit to your question.  I will defer to others more statistically minded than me on the desirability of using that tool rather than [Hot Spot Analysis (Getis-Ord Gi*) (Spatial Statistics)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Hot_Spot_Analysis_Getis_Ord_Gi/005p00000010000000/).

Comment: Space-Time Cluster Analysis can also produce heat maps http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Space_Time_Cluster_Analysis/005p00000056000000/

Answer (score 2):

Both of the recommended methods above should be able to produce a hot spot map, but I'm not sure about your representation of the speed of the vehicle unless that's an attribute in the point shapefile.

Comment: Well I'm also not really sure about my process. I just want to identify areas where there is a high number of cars with speed < 20, for example. So to identify areas with traffic jams or something like this.
Actually these values are not really countable and I think I will need countable values in order to produce hotspot maps, if I understood that correctly.

Comment: That's right, the hotspot map will give you a static representation (or snapshot, if you will) of the conditions at any given moment. To represent the speed of something in motion would be extremely more complicated and would require individual sensors for each vehicle (like a smartphone app) or transportation data.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Spatial Join prior to the Hot Spot analysis. Use spatial join to calculate average speed of cars on segments of your road network. In order to do that set Target feature as your road segment, join feature as your car points. You will see list of all fields below, select the field that consists of your car's speed. (Since not all points will intersect with your segment, you can set a tolerance for the join) Right click on it and select "Mean" from calculation method.

When it finishes calculation, each of your segments will have average speed of cars that passes through that segment. After you have this information you can use any statistical method to define hot and cold areas. I would basically use reclassification as we already know what is low and what is high. That's up to your requirement.